# Where can I find my Localizeable.strings file?

Tags: iphone, localization

I created a View-Based project in Xcode, but I find no Localizeable.strings file for doing my localization. Must I run genstrings first to create this? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare all your localizable text with NSLocalizedString before running genstrings will produce anything useful.

I would recommend declaring all your text definitions with NSLocalizedString instead of inside Interface Builder XIBs as it is easier to get a text file translated than a XIB file.

Just make sure to allow 50% more space than you need for your English strings, as English is generally more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you must run generate strings,

```
ibtool --generate-strings-file Example.strings en.lpoj/Example.xib
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, genstrings creates the Localizeable.strings file.  You can run it from the command line like this:

```
genstrings Classes/*.m
```

I found [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone) to be helpful.